# A common app for multiple existing apps

Tags: .net, user-interface, asp.net-core, identityserver3

I have multiple SPA's developed my different teams using different front end technologies, for ex:-

1. App1 (Angular2,WebAPI)
2. App2 (AngularJS,MVC)

and so on..

I have the task of building one APP which  combines these multiple SPA's on one website

All the SPA are using Identity server 3. I have thought of the following approaches

1. iFrame/Object
2. XhR calls to get the html and load them on the new app I am building

But both these approaches didn't work due to CORS errors from Identity server  which are used by the APPS.

What other smart approach could I use considering the security aspects I already have in place?

Comment: Umm... how about *actually* building one app that combines both? You'll have to rewrite code, of course, but I can almost assure you that the project request is to have one app that *replaces* the two old apps, not something that requires the two old apps stick around.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, Thanks. But the existing apps have a lot of functionality which can't be rewritten any time soon.

Comment: Hard to know if this will work based on your brief details, but you could try a [proxy](https://josephwoodward.co.uk/2016/07/proxying-http-requests-asp-net-core-using-kestrel).